# What causes this error message when using the postgres pg_dump command?

Tags: postgresql, google-compute-engine, rhel, pg-dump

I am attempting to dump an entire PG Database from hosting on a GCP/GCE instance ( RHEL 8.x VM ).

The purpose is to transfer the .sql file to another RHEL 8.x VM on GCE and restore the database.

---

I am running this script as OS user **'postgres'**

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

export PGUSER=<pg_user>
export PG_DATABASE=<pg_db>
export PGHOSTADDR=<pg_ip_addr>
export PGPORT=5432
SQL_FILE=<pg_db>.sql

export PGPASSWORD=<passwd>

pg_dump \
        --format plain \
        --no-owner \
        --verbose \
        --file $SQL_FILE \
        $PG_DATABASE
```

If there is anything else recommended in a script to dump a database to a .sql file for restoration:

1. anything recommended adding to the script,
2. or any way to improve the script that you are aware of), please advise.

---

I get this error when running the script: (have PostGIS installed)

```
pg_dump: last built-in OID is 16383
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: identifying extension members
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for table us_lex
pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE public.us_lex IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

Why is permission denied when running as OS user `postgres`.

What permission would I need to add (full/exact command), to add whatever permissions are needed?

Or how could I exclude this table?  I don't think I need it, and it would be recreated with the installation of a new Postgres instance.

Answer (score 2):

What probably confuses you is that the permissions denied are not operating system permissions, but database permissions.

The database user used for `pg_dump` is `<pg_user>`, and that database user obviously does not have the `SELECT` privilege on the table `public.us_lex`.

Comment: OK, perfect, that was the issue, I missed changing that to 'postgres' in the script.  Thank You!